# How to hide a section in grid that i don't use in media query?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So, i have a grid template, that have aside

```
grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header header header header"
    "nav section section section section section section aside"
    "nav section section section section section section aside"
    "nav section section section section section section aside"
    "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer";
```

but when I create a version for mobile, i don't have to use an aside section in my template,
something like:

```
grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "nav"
      "section"
      "section"
      "section"
      "section"
      "section"
      "footer";
```

I used display:none; to aside div, but it actually does nothing, and the aside section comes out after the template. How can I hade the aside section so it won't be visible?

Answer (score 0):

use `visibility:hidden;` in place of display:none;